# Scenario.getSourceTagNames not including tags under examples section of a scenario outline

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm looping through scenario.getSourceTagNames() within the @after tearDown method but the tags within my example section are not being shown as part of this list. I see this question has been asked a few times here but I'm afraid the solutions I found haven't been able to fix my issue so far (answers usually suggest updating the cucumber-jvm version).  These are my pom configs.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue to do with dependencies on the pom file as per @marit suggestion.

This is what I have now under my pom file in case it may be helpful to someone else.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: You can remove `cucumber-jvm`, `cucumber-core` and `gherkin`. They're either transitive dependencies of the other ones or not used.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are on the latest (or very recent) Cucumber **version**.
However, try using `<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>` (**cucumber-java** instead of **cucumber-jvm**).

Also, remove the following dependencies to avoid clashes / problems, as they are transitive dependencies of cucumber:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message. I'm afraid I tried following the suggestion but still couldn't get it to work. This is my repo if wanting to have a look? https://bitbucket.org/francislainy-campos/seleniumdemo/src/scenario_outline_tags_issue/. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, made the sample project small enough with only three small files puls the pom with only one dependency and the issue is still happening.

Comment: Hi, yes, you're right in regard to the issue being to do with the dependencies. I've updated that now with the newest ones and it's working so upvoted your answer. Thanks a lot. :)